# Elixir Phoenix application with Channels websockets not working on Google AppEngin

Tags: google-app-engine, websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I tried to run an Elixir web app with Channels, but it didn't work on AppEngine Flex.I used this instructions: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-google-app-engine

My app is very very simple, only a hello world websockets app (https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html). It works locally. 
When deployed on App Engine, ordinary HTTP requests work, but socket features don't propagate to different clients. 
Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is there any limitation on AppEngine side?

Comment: The flex runtime for Elixir is experimental and if you're still getting unexpected results without any actionable information, then I highly suggest that you create a new issue on the [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/elixir-runtime) along with reproducible code.

Comment: Is there an error code that you're receiving on the elixir side or in the browser? Can you share the code?